# CustomLayout for Spark logging

Tags: apache-spark

I am facing a strange issue while running a spark application. For my application ( spark and non spark ) , we have written a custom JsonLogLayout to log messages in Json format.

While running the spark job with following command , logs are getting written in JSON . So far so good

> spark-submit --verbose --files "/tmp/log4j.properties" 
>     --driver-java-options "-Dconf.dir=/etc/myapp/conf 
>      -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///tmp/log4j.properties"
>    --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dconf.dir=/etc/myapp/conf -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///tmp/log4j.properties  "
>    --class myapp.TestSpark.TestApp target/TestSpark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

As our environment is secured and we use kerberos , I need to pass **keytab and principal information** to spark job . So now command is as follows

> spark-submit --verbose --files "/tmp/log4j.properties" --driver-java-options "-Dconf.dir=/etc/myapp/conf -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///tmp/log4j.properties"
>   --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dconf.dir=/etc/myapp/conf -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///tmp/log4j.properties " --keytab /etc/security/keytabs/application.keytab --principal myapp_runtime@MYAPP.DEV.TEST.COM  --class myapp.TestSpark.TestApp target/TestSpark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

And from here spark job starts failing. I am getting below error

```
 `  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: myapps.custom.layout.JsonLogLayout
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(L`
```

I am not sure why spark is throwing this error and how can I resolve this ?